# parsing tree of text with regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex

please help! I need to create code/regexes for parsing the following text into a tree:

```
some text I want to ignore==toplevel==
some text, with newlines maybe

===nextlevel===
more text. This is a child node of 'toplevel'

===anotherchild===
this is a sibling of 'nextlevel' and a child of 'toplevel'====leaf====
this is a child of 'anotherchild'
====leaf2====
sibling of 'leaf' & child of 'anotherchild'

===child3===
this is a sibling of 'anotherchild' and 'nextlevel' and a child of 'toplevel'
```

etc. You get the idea.

I can't stop the sub levels from matching along with the toplevel. I've tried ={2} but the === and ==== still match. Just getting a match which extracted all the text following '==toplevel==' would be a start. I can't seem to get the newlines to be ignored/eaten.

Any help much appreciated!
Charlie.

Comment: How are you planning on storing the results?

Comment: In a tree of structs of some kind, not sure yet, why?

Comment: Well, because you can't expect concrete answers without it. That said, there isn't a concrete question in a way. Here's the generic regex for you `(==+).*?\1\n` - works in regex engine (which... you don't mention either) that support back references

Answer (score 0):

The following regex will match the first line: "^==[^=]". That is, a line starting with two equal signs followed by something which is not an equal sign. You can use analogous patterns for the other levels.

Newline skipping/processing really depends on how you read the text. I would process newlines in the input routine, if possible, rather than trying to match them with the regexes.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely specify the problem - the node tags are not tied to the start of any lines, and also might have things on the line after them. I'll edit the question to make this more clear

Comment: aha! actually, the node tags DO always end with a CRLF, which could help a lot. Edited again...

Comment: ={2,5}((\w|\s)+)=+\r\n gets me the tags, I guess I'll just parse the text in between manually. thanks!

Comment: The problem is how do I get the text from between the matches? Sorry, I'm not having much luck with the documentation and none of the examples are quite helping...

Answer (score 0):

Just match all the `=+(name)=+` strings, and then *count the number of =* in code.